# net::err_content_length_mismatch 200 (ok) django, apache

Tags: django, apache

My django website sometimes cannot open images and the error message is:

> "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH"

However, when I open the link next to the error message on a new tab, the image is loading. I am using Apache, not nginx.

[Here's how image looks like when I tried to open on a new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXYVn.jpg)

As you can see it's not fully loaded!

Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to fix it. Of course it was an apache problem. First I have activated my `sudo a2enmod expires` then added `ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"` to my media and static Directory in mysite.conf file.

Comment: im also getting this issue, using nginix and react @shux121995 did you find any solution